# How do I list all the column names in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

Is there a query I can write to search all the column names for a particular database in Netezza?

Answer (score 11):

Within the same database you can use the following query:

```
select *
from _v_odbc_columns1
where column_name like '%columnname%'
```

or a less Netezza specific query

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%columnname%'
```

Comment: This was the best answer for me because same code worked well on MS Sql Server as well as Netezza.  Huge saving of effort!

Comment: How do you list all columns for all databases in the server?

Answer (score 9):

The important catalog views in netezza system are listed below

- `_V_USER`: the user view gives information about the users in the netezza system.
- `_V_TABLE`: the table view contains the list of tables created in the netezza performance system.
- `_V_RELATION_COLUMN`: the relation column system catalog view contains the columns available in a table.
- `_V_TABLE_INDEX`: this system catalog contains the information about the 
  indexes created on table. netezza does not support creating indexes on a table as of now.
- `_V_OBJECTS`: lists the different objects like tables, view, functions etc. available in the netezza.

Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN
WHERE
    ATTNAME like '%GEO%' --SPECIFY COLUMN NAME
    AND type = 'TABLE'
```

Answer (score 3):

You would access something similar to an information_schema.
Column Name, %COW%', would use % as a wildcard...gathering any column that has 'COW' in the name

```
SELECT * 
FROM _V_SYS_COLUMNS 
WHERE 
COLUMN_NAME like '%COW%' 
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DEV' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME 
;
```