# In netezza aginity how to get the structure of the table

Tags: netezza

In Oracle, we can give like desc table_name, but as I am using the Netezza, so I couldn't get the description of the tables. If anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all the column names in Netezza?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607280/how-do-i-list-all-the-column-names-in-netezza)

Answer (score 5):

Right click on Table in `Object Browser --> Script --> DDL to query Window`

There is another nzsql command : `\d <TABLE_NAME>`
The nzsql commands apply only if you use command line (eg:putty). Not on Aginity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a metadata query to give the structure of tables and views. There is one row per column, and it describes the data types.

```
SELECT *
FROM _v_relation_column
```